# Selenium webriver do not working after update

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

15 and I need to upgrade to 4.1 but it is still not working.

my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import os.path
import requests

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\geckodriver.exe")


tag = "test"
driver.get("https://www.pexels.com/search/" + tag +"/?orientation=landscape&size=medium")

images = driver.find_elements_by_name('img')
l = 0
for image in images:
    src = image.get_attribute('src')
    
    
    l = +1
   

    try:
        if src[8] == "i":
            
            if src[26] == "p":
                src = src.replace('?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500', '')
            
                
                if os.path.exists(tag+".txt"):
                    links = open(tag+".txt", "a")
                    link = src + "\n"
                    links.write(link)
                
                else:
                
                    links = open(tag+".txt", "w")
                    driver.quit()
```

I do not remember these `images = driver.find_elements_by_name` very well so I do not know how I had it but important is it is working I read on the Internet something like I need to use A **Be** but is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the webdriver manager for selenium. It will download and cache the latest driver.

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

s = Service(GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=s)

tag = "test"
url = "https://www.pexels.com/search/" + tag +"/?orientation=landscape&size=medium"
driver.get(url)
images = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'img')
...
```